# Call Web Api from MVC Controller and post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a logger in Web Api controller, which inserts posted files in the log txt file. This is my ValuesController's Post method:

```
public void Post([FromBody] SmsObject sms)
{
    Logger.Info(string.Format("Text : {0}, Amount : {1}, Phone : {2}", sms.SMSText, sms.Amount, sms.Phone));
}
```

this is my Model :

```
public class SmsObject
{          
    public string SMSText { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm testing this Web API in Postman, it works. But now I want to call this method from another MVC solution and post data.

How can I use MVC controller to call this Web API?

Comment: Your controller shouldn't be directly calling this service. You should encapsulate that logic into its own class. And as far the library you use, there's plenty of HTTP clients for C#. Have you researched any?

Comment: I suggest you do a web search for "C# HTTP client" and research the available libraries based on the usual criteria: project activity, documentation, who's using it, how clever the name is etc. Once you've picked a library, follow their documentation and try to hit your web service. If you get stuck on a specific part of your implementation, then provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll have a more appropriate question. As it stands now, your question is a little too broad to be answered. You learn to program by doing!